# Haskell transpose chars in String

Tags: string, haskell, char, transpose

I'm trying to write a function of the form:

```
f :: String -> [String]
f st = ...
```

It should display all possible transposions of chars in the String.
For example:

```
ghci> f "string"
["tsring","srting","stirng","strnig","strign"]
```

As you can see it should only transpose the next char with the current one.
I currently have:

```
f :: String -> [String]
f [] = []
f (x:xs) = ...
```

but i dont know how to actually transpose the chars.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
f :: String -> [String]
f (x:y:xs) = (y:x:xs) : map (x:) (f (y:xs))
f      xs  = []
```

Note, that `f [x]` returns `[]`, but it's easy to fix, if this is desired.

Comment: I didnt know you can do (x:y:xs), thank you! Thats what i was looking for.